# Let an APK file run Automated Script

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, android-uiautomator

I want to execute automated script on different apps using apk file.

I'm using Appium for testing and it's not possible to wrap Appium by apk file because it's working by creating sockets and drivers.

Can you please suggest different tool that may help me to perform actions on my app and eventually build an apk file that can execute automated script on installed app?

Few users are using my app with different equipment and need to perform multiple actions to on different tools and apps then use my app, I want to make using my app simple for my users. So that I want to create apk file that performs all the actions they do on another apps.

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible and is not normal to do that, otherwise there will be no problems to exploit the system by malware apps. Imagine the situation when a malware can run a automated script to install another malware or a advertising useless app =)

But... of course there are a few solutions)) You can run adb shell scripts, with root privileges even a restricted commands like " adb shell pm install".

In my opinion best approach is to make a responsive UI which will inform users about your intents to install apps or configure some internal things.

Comment: I tried to execute adb commands in the activity but nothing happened, isn't working.
Can you suggest good framework for that?